# Can I append question marks to affirmative sentence to confirm/ask something

Tags: questions, interrogatives, question-marks

Consider the sentences:

> It is raining there?
>
> You're gay?
>
> You will be able to finish this by monday?

First sentence means: I think it is raining there and I am confirming it.

Second means: I am asking if the person is gay?

Third means: I am asking if you are able to finish this by monday?

---

So are my sentences grammatically correct? Also are my explanation of these sentence is correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are all equivalent to the ordinary questions formed with subject/auxiliary inversion.

> Is it raining there?
>   Are you gay?
>   Will you be able to finish this by Monday?

The question mark indicates the rising pitch at the end which distinguishes your sentences from ordinary declaratives.

Note that these 'declarative' questions are only used "echoically": repeating the substance of something that has been said to get confirmation of what you have heard.

Comment: You can make questions in this way, but if you do not make just the right amount of rising pitch at the ends of these statements (to turn them into questions), some people may not understand that you are actually making a question. Also, some statements don't fully make sense. "You're gay" as a statement is not necessary - you don't need me to tell you that! "You're gay?" is a question, and "You're gay!" is an exclamation which could have a good meaning or a bad one. Rather than relying on rising pitch, it is always correct and safe to make actual questions in the way StoneyB has explained.